# winsock error after some days working properly

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp, winsock

I have a program that was working totally properly but after 2 days running, it started working, connection() isn't working anymore (TIMEOUT error) and I cannot realise why could that be happening.

I stopped the program and restarted again... but it doesn't work anymore.

I've read a lot of literature about it, saying that winsock could be corrupted, etc. I've tried every solution I found in the internet, like reseting winsock entries and TCP/IP stack... but nothing works...

Has anybody had this trouble and solved it??

Thanks, I'd appreciate any advice you could give me...

Comment: Please provide the *exact* socket error you get (i.e. the value `WSAGetLastError` returns after a function fails).

Comment: Sorry, didn't remember the name, just ran it again and received WSATIMEDOUT
It's running on W7 32 bits

Comment: And you're certain that the system you try to connect to is up and running? Without any kind of network problems? Have you tried to `ping` it? No new firewall rules? That error is typical when there is some kind of network problem in the way.

Comment: yeah I ping it and it's running. The firewall is deactivated. I have a 3-party software that's able to connect with the device, but I designed the software in order to do some automatic routines.

The software uses another port than the one that I use. The strange issue for me is that it was working properly and then stopped working at some time...

Comment: I suggest you try to use some kind of network packet logging on both sides, to see what's happening. And of course make sure that the actual program on the other end is still up and running and accepting connections (maybe the process/thread handling that port had a deadlock or crash?)

Comment: the problem is that I only can see the PC-side, on the other side there is another device I cannot access, but it should be accepting connections... I'll try it with wireshark... but if it's died while connecting, I don't expect to see any packet, maybe a SYN packet... but... not sure about it

Comment: Following your idea, I'll try to change the port I am trying to communicate, sadly I'll need to wait until monday since I don't have the device here.
I'll update the improvements I made as soon as possible.
Any other idea would also be appreciated

Comment: Is it possible that you queried the DNS name at the beginning and the IP for that name has since changed? Also, another thing to note, Winsock doesn't query the DNS server if windows still has a valid result from a previous query in it's cache.

Comment: Any 'literature ... saying that Winsock can be corrupted' is at least ten years out of date. Windows 98 was the last version where that sort of thing was possible.

Comment: @Waldermort: I am querying directly to a device's IP (connected to my LAN)

Comment: @EJP: Good to know, I found some also related to W7,but maybe they are not very believable